# Turn off radiators when windows open using SmartThings, Google Assistant and maybe Tado

Tags: smart-home, smart-assistants

I'm trying to setup a system, so when my windows are open, my radiator valve (in that room) turns off. And vice verca.

I have Google Assistant and SmartThings setup in my house.

I can see, that several thermostat controls have their own eco-system (I don't have any experience and I'm not connected to either):

- [Tado](https://www.tado.com/dk-en/products)
- [Netatmo](https://shop.netatmo.com/en-eu/energy/collective-heating/starter-pack)
- [Aqara](https://www.aqara.com/eu/product/radiator-thermostat-e1)
- [Nedis](https://nedis.com/en-us/product/home-living/climate/thermostats/550785816/brennenstuhlconnect-zigbee-smart-radiator-valve-ht-cz-01)

They all come with their own bridges, hubs and/or apps (eco-systems).
I purchased two Tado-thermostats and tried to set it up in the SmartThings-app, but it says 'Device not recognized' (or something like that), when I try to add it.

I'm based in Denmark and I have a Danfoss radiator valve(s).

Considering all of that, then these are my options/considerations:

### Option 1: Just having several eco-systems in my house

That means, having the SmartThings sensors to monitor when the windows are open/closed - and then figure out a way to send a signal to the Tado hub/switches, when that happens.

This seems suboptimal and error-prone.

I did find this guide here, which apparently is a [Tado-SmartThings integration](https://github.com/fuzzysb/Tado).
It seems quite technical, but maybe that is the way.

### Option 2: Find a thermostat compatible with SmartThings

I've Googled and Googled and Googled; and I can't find any that is obviously compatible. For each of the radiator valves, it always says: 'Compatible with Google Assistant', but never points out if it's compatible (or incompatible) with SmartThings.

I've also tried checking in the app, to click 'Add device'. I can find some devices and brands, but not any obvious clear threads to follow:

[image: SmartThings radiator valve and thermostats]

For instance, you can see that Netatmo is listed under 'Thermostat'. But that is sold with it's own hub. So does that mean that SmartThings can talk to the Netatmo-hub or can I also control *the individual* Netatmo radiator valves from SmartThings (which would be necessary, since that's where the starting-conditions (the window sensors) would be set up. Hmm, hmm, hmm!! So many questions.

### Option 3: Send command to Google Assistant from SmartThings

Since Tado is setup to Google Assistant, and SmartThings are *linked* to Google Assistant; I was thinking that I maybe could setup a SmartThings-routine that executed an 'Experimental Voice Command' via Google Assistant, when the window was opened.
But I can't seem to send anything that way (SmartThings -> Google Assistant) in my setup.

This too feels fragile and error-prone, - even if I got it to work.

### Option 4: Finding another eco-system that has both window-sensors and radiator valves

Just scrapping SmartThings for this operation, setting up the entire thing in another system.
Tado doesn't have window sensors.
It appears that [Netatmo does](https://www.netatmo.com/en-eu/smart-door-and-window-sensors), but I feel I'm making my home into a Frankenstein monster, by going this way.